# How to hide access token wihile Implementing social login with keycloak

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, keycloak

I have a social login keycloak instance, right now it is entirely written in the front end. Theres an option to login with google, on clicking on it it opens the google login popup and redirects me to the front end since I have set the redirect URL as front end.

One of the downsides to it is that it logs all the access tokens and refresh tokens in the network tab which seems a little unsafe to me. I want to ideally move all of the auth logic to the backend and have a wrapper around the code block such that in the front end on clicking the login with google it writes the token to backend cookie. I am not sure how to implement that.

This is how the front end keycloak auth part is written which ideally I want to move to backend express application.

```
loginUsingIdp = (idp: string, redirect_uri: string = this.redirectUri) => {
    
    this.kc.login({ idpHint: idp, redirectUri: redirect_uri });
  };
```

here idp string could be google | Microsoft

keycloak instance is created as

```
export class KeycloakAuth {
  private kc: any;
  private baseUrl: string;
  private redirectUri: string;
  private logoutUrl: string;
  username: string;

  constructor(initOpts: AuthProps) {
    const { clientId, url, realm, redirectUri, baseUrl } = initOpts;
    // See this link for more information on the keycloak object
    // https://www.this.kc.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_javascript_adapter
    this.kc = new Keycloak({ url, clientId, realm });
    console.log("this.kc", this.kc)
    this.redirectUri = redirectUri;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this.logoutUrl = `${url}/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=${baseUrl}`;
    this.username = "";

    //keycloak listeners to listen auth events
    this.kc.onAuthSuccess = () => {
      console.log("Authentication successful");
      this.setLocalstorage(true);
    };

    this.kc.onAuthError = (error: any) => {
      console.log("Authentication error", error);
    };

    this.kc.onTokenExpired = () => {
      console.log("Token expired");
      this.refreshData();
    };
    this.kc.onAuthRefreshSuccess = () => {
      console.log("token refreshed");
    };
    this.kc.onAuthLogout = () => {
      console.log("Logged Out");
    };
  }
```